# My bank error message appears regardless of condition and doesn't accept user input

Tags: java

I am having difficulty making sure the error message for choice 2 **only** appears if the number the user inputs is greater than their bank balance. Yet, it will appear even if the amount the user inputted is less than their bank balance. Playing around with it some more has now made my problems worse because the user has to input an answer more than once to get a response. If there are still things about the problem that are unclear please let me know. This is my first programming class and I have yet to figure out solutions on my own yet so any help would be very welcome.

```
//Part 2
            double balance = 0;
            BankAccount myBankAccount=new BankAccount(500.00);

        myBankAccount.deposit(1000.00);
        System.out.println(myBankAccount.getBalance());
        myBankAccount.withdrawal(600.00);
        System.out.println(myBankAccount.getBalance());

        //Part 3
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

        int choice;
        System.out.println("Welcome to M&T Bank!");
        System.out.println("Select a Banking Option Below");
        myBankAccount.menu();
        choice=input.nextInt();
        while(choice<4&&choice>0)
        {
            if(choice==1)
            {
                System.out.println("How much will you deposit?");
                myBankAccount.deposit(input.nextDouble());
            }
            else if(choice==2)
            {
                System.out.println("How much will you withdraw?");
                if(input.nextDouble()>balance)
                {
                    while(input.nextDouble()>balance)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Your account has insufficient funds. Your balance is: "+myBankAccount.getBalance());
                        System.out.println("How much will you withdraw?");
                        myBankAccount.withdrawal(input.nextDouble());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    myBankAccount.withdrawal(input.nextDouble());
                }
            }
            else if(choice==3)
            {
                System.out.println("Your balance is: "+myBankAccount.getBalance());
            }
            System.out.println("Welcome to M&T Bank!");
            System.out.println("Select a Banking Option Below");
            myBankAccount.menu();
            choice=input.nextInt();
        }
        if(choice==4)
        {
            System.out.println("Thank you! Goodbye.");
        }
```

Comment: Language? We can't read your mind!

Comment: Sorry its Java.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `input.nextDouble()`, you're reading another input. Also, you're withdrawing regardless of the balance. Also, `balance` is 0. Try this:

```
else if (choice == 2) {
    System.out.println("How much will you withdraw?");
    double amount;
    while ((amount = input.nextDouble()) > myBankAccount.getBalance()) {
        System.out.println("Your account has insufficient funds. Your balance is: "+myBankAccount.getBalance());
        System.out.println("How much will you withdraw?");
    }
    myBankAccount.withdrawal(amount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    BankAccount myBankAccount = new BankAccount(500.00);

    myBankAccount.deposit(1000.00);
    System.out.println(myBankAccount.getBalance());
    myBankAccount.withdrawal(600.00);
    System.out.println(myBankAccount.getBalance());

    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = input.nextInt();

    while (choice > 4 || choice < 1){
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = input.nextInt();}


    System.out.println("Welcome to M&T Bank!");
    System.out.println("Select a Banking Option Below");
    myBankAccount.menu();

    Switch(choice){
    case 1:{
           System.out.println("How much will you deposit?");
           myBankAccount.deposit(input.nextDouble());}

    case 2:{
            System.out.println("How much will you withdraw?");
            while(input.nextDouble() > myBankAccount.getBalance(){
            System.out.println("Your account has insufficient funds.");
            System.out.println("Your balance is: "+myBankAccount.getBalance());
            System.out.println("How much will you withdraw?");}
            myBankAccount.withdrawal(input.nextDouble());
            }

    case 3: System.out.println("Your balance is: "+myBankAccount.getBalance());
    case 4 : System.out.println("Thank you! Goodbye.");
```